# Notification-like list element deletion on slide-out in Android

Tags: android, android-listview, android-animation, android-notifications

I wonder how can I make a `ListView`'s elements slide out on `slide`, like the way you can `slide` a notification from the notifications bar in `Android`. This is my situation:

I have a list of items, and, when the user wants to remove an item from this list, she simply slides an element towards the edge of the screen. I would like this slide-out to be visible, e.g. to use some kind of animation that slides out that given `View` holding the item.

Here are some images to illustrate this.

First, this is the normal state of the notification.

[image: Normal state of notification]

And then, this is during slide-out

[image: State during slide-out]

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Roman Nurik (Android developer advocate) created [a quick-and-dirty swipe-to-dismiss implementation](https://gist.github.com/2980593). Jake Wharton [backported it](https://github.com/JakeWharton/SwipeToDismissNOA), using NineOldAndroids, to work on earlier Android versions. You might give one of those a try.

Answer (score 7):

The Android class [com.android.systemui.statusbar.policy.NotificationRowLayout](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.1_r1/com/android/systemui/statusbar/policy/NotificationRowLayout.java?av=f) (Android 4.1.1 versions throughout) appears to be the manager of the notification bar rows, and it uses a helper class [com.android.systemui.SwipeHelper](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.1_r1/com/android/systemui/SwipeHelper.java?av=f) which appears to do precisely the sort of thing you want.

So [NotificationRowLayout](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.1_r1/com/android/systemui/statusbar/policy/NotificationRowLayout.java?av=f) is an example of the use of [SwipeHelper](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.1_r1/com/android/systemui/SwipeHelper.java?av=f) which is hopefully the thing you were looking for!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I found CommonsWare's answer a bit better. Note that I upvoted your answer, though.